# Excel count non null and non empty strings values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a sheet like below

```
 A            B        C      D
1 EmpID      Param1  Param2  Param3 
2 Emp2       100              30
3 Emp3       20      
4 Emp4       10       25         
5 Emp5       120      40       18
6 Emp7       333      55       89
```

I want the count of all rows where we have some non null value in both param2 and param 3

Formula used

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,"<>", D:D,"<>")-1  #-1 is to remove the first row heading of all columns
```

Ideally count should be 2 since only 2 rows (row 5 and row 6 ) have some value in both parameters, but I am getting count as 5, so it is also counting blanks/empty strings as a value. How to calculate the rows which have basically some value and exclude the empty strings or null values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use SUMPRODUCT, eg:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C6<>"")*(D2:D6<>""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those cells are probably not empty but holding strings like `=""` of some sort. But since you apply it to numeric values, why not using:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,">0",D:D,">0")
```

Which also eliminates the need for `-1`. If all your values happen to be text values looking like numbers you could apply `SUMPRODUCT()` as per the other answer, or use:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,"?*",D:D,"?*")-1
```

Comment: @Noob, that means all your values are actually text values looking like numeric values. You could either use the `SUMPRODUCT()` alternative as per SJR or use: `=COUNTIFS(C:C,"?*",D:D,"?*")-1`

Comment: @SJR, it's allright, nothing we can do about that =). You should see what happens around other popular tags like regex...

Comment: @noob - didn't meant to imply it was you, just whoever did downvote as no good reason to do so as far as I can see.

Comment: @JvdV - perhaps we should be grateful that VBA is something of a backwater!